# FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "gs" not installed (Android)

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

I'm attempting to connect to a public Google cloud storage bucket, using code based upon the example provided by Google at https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage-nio under 'Quickstart' and 'Accessing Files'

I added the following line to my app module's build.gradle (Google's documentation says to use 'compile', but Android Studio complains that it has to be either 'implementation' or 'api'):

`implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-nio:0.120.0-alpha'`

My code:

```
try {
    Path path = Paths.get(URI.create("gs://gcp-public-data-goes-16"));
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : lines) {
        Log.i("bucket", line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("bucket", e.toString());
}
```

It compiles, deploys to the emulator (API 28 w/Google, x86_64), then dies with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pantherkitty.experiment.bucket/pantherkitty.experiment.bucket.MainActivity}: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "gs" not installed
```

I'm mystified by the "Provider 'gs' not installed" error... isn't that what the library included by Gradle from google-cloud-nio is supposed to do?

If it matters, the project itself was created in Android Studio 3.5.3 as a new project with blank activity. I'm running it in the emulator using the x86_64 Android 9 ROM with Google API support. Google's docs give the impression that the only dependency that needs to be added is the Gradle reference to google-cloud-nio, which I did.

Comment: The preferred way to access Cloud Storage buckets on Android is via Firebase SDKs.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start

Comment: It might be the "preferred" way, but is it literally the ONLY way? Or is Google's official Java library at least theoretically supposed to work with Android (or unquestionably known to NOT work with Android)?

Comment: I don't know, but I would prefer the Android library because it's optimized to work well on mobile devices with spotty connections.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to admit it, but Firebase scares me. I've read dozens of horror stories involving developers who casually added Firebase to an Android project, used some aspect of its functionality without fully understanding every last bit of esoterica related to it, then found themselves suddenly threatened out of the blue with Google's account death penalty over some default/implicit framework behavior that wasn't even necessarily obvious, let alone intended to be malicious. That's *terrifying*.

Comment: Would you care to share a few of these dozens of stories?  Most problems that the Firebase team deals with are typically user error.  I've never heard of a problem with Cloud Storage.  It's usually misunderstandings about other products, specifically database products being used incorrectly.  Firebase support typically gives temporary credits to those with misunderstandings, so they can continue to work with a new, correct understanding.

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like I just got a really, really scary & warped first impression of Firebase arising from horror stories specific to Firebase crash reporting and Google's suspension of developer accounts out of the blue for failing to disclose its use of Android's advertising ID. It ended up poisoning my view of EVERYTHING associated with the name "Firebase", to the point where my instant reaction from that point forward was to run away screaming in terror at the very mention of its name. Upon further research, it appears my fears might have been unwarranted, or at least excessive.